# MVC date time picker

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have MVC datetime picker to get date. When I add date it will show only date. But when I show the date it will show with the time. I need to remove tiime from this.

This is View:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.date, new { @class = "form-control input-sm", @data_provide = "datepicker" })
```

This is Modal:

```
[Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = "Required", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.Resources))]
        [Display(Name = "Maintenance Date")]
        [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:yy/MM/dd}")]
        public virtual DateTime date { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

can you give a try to below code?

```
@Html.TextBox(model => model.date, Model.date.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"),new { @class = "form-control input-sm", @data_provide = "datepicker" })
```

OR

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.date, new { Value = Model.date.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy"), @class = "form-control input-sm", @data_provide = "datepicker" })
```

Answer (score 0):

Add "{0:yy/MM/dd}" to your HTML helper, so it now looks like

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.date, "{0:yy/MM/dd}", new { @class = "form-control input-sm", @data_provide = "datepicker" })
```